# How to display choiceType values in Symfony as Colors

Tags: css, forms, symfony, bootstrap-4, choicefield

I want to save an integer value in database and display it as a color but I'm not finding the right way to make it.

My Form looks like this one:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('risk', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => 
            'level.0' => 1,
            'level.1' => 2,
            'level.2' => 3,
            'level.3' => 4,
            'level.4' => 5
        ],
    ]);
}
```

It should look like this form at the end:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks for Veve but his Answer was very short and not completed, I got to convert the choice type to radio buttons by adding expanded => true and multiple => false. For more Info see:  [Symfony Select Tag](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons)

```
$builder->add('risk', ChoiceType::class, [
     'choices' => [
        'level-0' => 1,
        'level-1' => 2,
        'level-2' => 3,
        'level-3' => 4,
        'level-4' => 5
     ],
        'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
             return ['class' => 'risk_'.strtolower($key)];
         },
     'expanded' => true,
     'multiple' => false,
     'placeholder' => false
]);
```

Then i used a table to display the values from the form.

```
<table class="table risk-colors-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="risk_level-text">Text</td>
        <td class="risk-option level-0">{{ form_row(form.risk[0])}}</td>
        <td class="risk-option level-1">{{ form_row(form.risk[1])}}</td>
        <td class="risk-option level-2">{{ form_row(form.risk[2])}}</td>
        <td class="risk-option level-3">{{ form_row(form.risk[3])}}</td>
        <td class="risk-option level-4">{{ form_row(form.risk[4])}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And i added this css to make a nice design using the classes that i added before and to hide the radio buttons and labels:

```
.risk_level-text {
   vertical-align: center!important;
}

.level-0 {
    background: #63d06c;
}

.level-1 {
    background: #a7e35c;
}

.level-2 {
    background: #fdf74d;
}

.level-3 {
    background: #f0a725;
}

.level-4 {
    background: #ee0018;
}

.risk-colors-table {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.risk-colors-table tr {
    border:2px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.risk-option {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: center!important;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: 28px;
    width:19%;
}

.risk-option label {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.risk-option.active {
    border:3px solid #3362b1;
}

.risk-colors-table td {
    margin: 10px 1px;
}
```

In JavaScript i had to add this function to make the radio button active when i click on the table td:

```
$(function () {
    $('.risk-option').click(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            var $radioBtn = $('.risk-option.active input[type="radio"]');

            if ($radioBtn.is(':checked') === true) {
                $radioBtn.filter('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

I worked so much on it and i hope it could help someone. The final results is exactly how it shown in the picture in my mean question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [choice_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) to add specific CSS class to these choices, and the corresponding class definitions in your CSS to render these choices as you like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('risk', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => 
            'level.0' => 1,
            'level.1' => 2,
            'level.2' => 3,
            'level.3' => 4,
            'level.4' => 5
        ],
        'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
           return ['class' => 'level_'.strtolower($key)];
        }
    ]);
}
```

CSS: (only the text color as example, the rest is up to you)

```
.level_0 {
    color: red;
}
.level_1 {
    color: orange;
}
.level_2 {
    color: yellow;
}
.level_3 {
    color: light_green;
}
.level_4 {
    color: green;
}
```